# How to add custom ribbon button on sitepage on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, custom, modern-pages

[image]

I am trying to add a button on Modern SitePage on SharePoint 365. Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Old thread but, did you find a way to solve your issue? I have the same case and ListView Command Sets are still not able to do this...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add it by SPFX ListView Command Set Extension.

Official demo:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api

Comment: I already created the ribbon button for ListView, Document, and PageList.  I need a custom button on the ribbon on Modern SitePages.